# Time difference and parsing into Time datatype in PHP

Tags: php, parsing

In database the data type of variable that store time difference is Time and the trigger where I calculate the time return string. So some time the difference will be 00:00:00.

How to parse this time (string) to data type Time so it will saved into database correctly.

I use below code to manipulate the time.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime(@@startTime);
$datetime2 = new DateTime(getCurrentTime());
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$elapsed = $interval->format('%i minutes').' '.$interval->format('%s seconds');
$totalTime = $elapsed;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the below to change `time()` into the correct format for MySQL.

```
$expire = time() + (86400 * 28);
$expiration = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $expire);
```